# Como dar las medidas en milimetros en itextsharp C#

Tags: c#, itextsharp

Quiero imprimir una etiqueta de 50x30 mm en itextsharp , pero no se cuanto darle de tamaño.

Por ejemplo a estas variables:

```
float myWidth = 50 milimetros;
float myHeight = 30 milimetros;
var pgSize = new Rectangle(myWidth, myHeight);
```

No se como hacer la conversión. Si alguien me puede ayudar, se lo agradecería.

Saludos

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usa el método `millimetersToPoints()` de la clase [Utilities](https://api.itextpdf.com/iText5/java/5.5.13.3/com/itextpdf/text/Utilities.html#millimetersToPoints-float-). Ejemplo:

```
var myWidth = Utilities.millimetersToPoints(50);
```